# отсеивание пустых переменных

Tags: php

Форма передает 50 chekbox b1, b2 и тд.
и 50 chekbox r1, r2 и тд.
далее принимаю их

```
if (isset($_POST['b1'])) {$b1 = $_POST['b1'];} else {$b1 = '';} 
if (isset($_POST['b2'])) {$b2 = $_POST['b2'];} else {$b2 = '';}
if (isset($_POST['r1'])) {$r1 = $_POST['r1'];} else {$r1 = '';}
```

и так далее
так вот первый вопрос так как 100 строк очень много, как оптимизировать
в цикле или может по другому присваивание переменных `$b1 = $_POST['b1']`
и второй вопрос
Как в цикле вывести те переменные в которых есть данные, (выбранные чекбоксы)
Спасибо
Надеюсь поймете что я имел в виду )

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type=checkbox name="b[1]">
<input type=checkbox name="b[2]">
...

<?php
$checked_b = array_keys($_POST['b']);
```

если нужно еще и неотмеченные получать, то только арифметикой: в цикле от 1 до 50 проверять, для каких значения отсутствуют.